# Determining if a location is in the London Congestion Charge Zone

Tags: driving, london, fees-and-charges

I need to find out if this primary school falls within the London Congestion Charge zone: **St Anne`s Catholic Primary School, 6 Durham Street, Vauxhall, London**. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I fail to see how this is directly related to travel. Sounds to me like you could very well be a commuting Londoner.

Comment: This is a lazy question  https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/congestion-charge

Comment: **And SE11 5JA is not for Dunbar street, that is SE27 9JY**. http://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I've made it more general - I think a visitor might well wonder about this or need to know.

Comment: @pnuts 4 bare meta links just labelled "Related" doesn't feel helpful. Maybe include question titles, or "here's a similar question from 11 months ago that asked about [whatever] on meta"

Comment: @JanDoggen I live in Canada. If I don't know that URL am I lazy? Or a visitor?

Comment: @KateGregory Googling 'London Congestion Charge'. First hit, then 3rd item, or top item in right side bar of its main page. That's where I found it  + that this cannot be a correct address. I'm not English either.

Comment: @JanDoggen we're supposed to embrace the nonGooglers and create answers that end up higher in Google results than the sources we drew on to create them. That's a system wide mandate. That's why LMGTFY links are banned.

Comment: @KateGregory I'll refrain from commenting (to the OP), that's better.

Comment: @KateGregory It seems extremely unlikely that a visitor to the UK would be interested in the specific location of a particular primary school. Furthermore, we can never be the best reference for where the London Congestion Zone is. We can certainly aspire to be the best place for explaining how the congestion zone works but this isn't a question about that.

Comment: A primary school does indeed seem an awkward thing to look for as a visitor — but maybe the grandparents just want to turn up for the school play as a surprise? (Choosing a ‘typical tourist target’ would have made the post unquestionably on-topic, imho.)

Comment: @pnuts Precisely my point.

Answer (score 11):

Use this page on the TfL website to confirm whether a specific location is within the congestion charging zone:

https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/congestion-charge

As of the date of this answer, Durham St in Vauxhall is just outside the zone:

https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/congestion-charge?Input=Durham%20Street,%20London,%20UK&InputGeolocation=0,0&googlePredictionId=EhlEdXJoYW0gU3RyZWV0LCBMb25kb24sIFVL

although the boundaries do change sometimes so after a few years it will be worth re-checking.

Taxis don't normally charge extra for going in the zone; car hire companies do. The charge only applies between 07:00 and 18:00 on weekdays:

> There is no charge on weekends, public holidays, between Christmas Day and New Year's Day inclusive, or between 18:00 and 07:00 on weekdays.

https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge/congestion-charge-zone

Answer (score -1):

In addition to it being *just* outside the congestion charge zone, if you drive there guided by your TomTom, there is a good chance that you find yourself on the wrong street, and you might not know whether you entered the congestion charge zone or not, and there is no way to find out other than waiting for a £100 pound fine - so you have to pay to be safe.

Now if you ask about that location because you expect to drive your kids there every morning, and after the third time you are sure you know the way, then you can go there without paying.

And remember that London doesn't only have a congestion charge zone, they also have a congestion zone which covers the congestion charge zone and a lot more of London :-( so consider googling how you get there by public transport. It's likely faster on weekdays in the daytime.

Comment: No, I meant congestion zone - anywhere you have congestion. Where you are often overtaken by pedestrians. Which is basically everywhere in London.

Comment: @pnuts: You don't know the place, you try following instructions, then suddenly something unexpected happens (because your TomTom is slow, streets are not laid out as you expect them to be, you went past a sign and immediately turn around. It happens. You don't know if you have to pay for taking a wrong turn and immediately turning around and leaving. And there is no way to find out. Which I assume is deliberate.

Comment: There is no place where you can ask "do I need to pay the congestion charge". There is no place where you can ask "how much do I owe you". You either pay (and you'll never know whether you had to or not), or you don't (and you either get a huge fine or you don't).